# Russian character typing

Tags: winedt, russian

Usually through my keyboard I type Chinese English and Korean And I add Russian keyboard so that I can type Russian in internet e.g. в а ф у п ы

But I can not type Russian in WinEdt When I am typing in Russian setting, two alphabets is automatically changed into Chinese character How can I solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance